# How do I find the XML error returned by an API call using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, webclient, webrequest

I've got an API that I'm trying to test. The API returns specific comments on errors.

Example:

```
<errors>
    <error>distance.out.of.range</error>
</errors>
```

When querying the API in Chrome or Firefox, I see this XML.

However, when querying with IE or with Powershell (both WebClient and WebRequest), I'm only able to see the "400" exception. I can't find the XML drilling down into the exception.

Handling the exception with a try/catch is fine, but I'm missing out on understanding the specifics of the failed query. How can I find the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to read the stream from the exception object

```
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
try {
    $res = $req.GetResponse()
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    $res = $_.Exception.Response
}
```

$res will have a method called GetResponseStream() that you can use to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try shuffling the output of the call into an object and see if that object has properties that contain the error.

```
$MyApiCall = New-WebRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you grab [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and inspect the request that works from Chrome and then the request that fails from PowerShell.  It might be just a matter of providing the correct headers.